# How can I copy boot.bin to SD card zynq board?

Tags: xilinx, zynq

I have a xilinx zynq board. I download file boot.bin and plug in the required cables. But i dont know how copy file boot.bin to SD card. I must use of ISE software?

Comment: do you know how to create the zImage and devicetree.dtb using the BOOT.bin?

Answer (score 2):

Setting up the SD card to boot on a Zynq board is very straightforward and doesn't require putting the bootloader in the MBR or other fancy filesystem tricks. The ISE software is not required once you have the boot.bin file.

- As other answers have said, you need to put the SD card into an SD card reader, and connect it to your computer.
- You need the SD card formatted as a FAT partition (Windows would do this by default).
- Simply copy the boot.bin to the card, as a normal file.
- See http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Prepare+Boot+Medium for detailed steps to do this in Linux.

If you're booting up an OS like Linux, you'll need extra files there too. See http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Prepare+boot+image (the FSBL and u-boot are included in the boot.bin that you have).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use an SD card reader? Laptops usually have them built in, or they make USB-to-SD converters that are cheap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the boot.bin file to the SD card, you should have a card reader of some sort (They are usually integrated in recent laptops).
However, if you want a fast solution to check your application functionality other than JTag, and couldn't find an SD reader, you can always use your mcs file and boot from QSPI.

You can refer to ZedBoard Configuration and Booting Guide listed in this link 
http://www.zedboard.org/support/design/1521/11